# CSS not applying when mat-expansion-panel-header is in child component

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have a component that uses MatExpansionPanel to display a list of products.

I'm using some CSS to hide the overflow of the product's description. Please, see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-puq5zc-uv2kpc) for the current looking.

So I'm trying to extract the panel header into a child component and to apply the exact same CSS to it. However, the CSS doesn't seems to be working. Please, see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-puq5zc-v1hchm).

Am I doing something wrong there ? Or is it that this Angular Material component is implemented in a way that it shouldn't be split in different components ?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your product-panel-header.component between a div with display:flex like this:

html:

```
<div class="panel-header">
  <mat-panel-title>
    {{product.noProduit}}
  </mat-panel-title>
  <mat-panel-description class="product-name">
    {{product.designation}}
  </mat-panel-description>
  <mat-panel-description>
    {{product.quantite}}(+{{product.supplement}})
  </mat-panel-description>
</div>
```

css:

```
.panel-header {
  display: flex;
}
```

see [working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-puq5zc-jryrwi)